# How to find a formula relating fibonacci sequence?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

By shifting property of fibonacci numbers,
$$F_{m+n} = F_m · F_{n+1} + F_{m-1} · F_n$$
where $F_k$ denotes the kth Fibonacci number .

I want to extend it to some n numbers .

So , how to find a formula for $F_{k_1+k_2+k_3+...+k_n}$ ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you already considered the obvious $F_{k_1+k_2+k_3} = F_{(k_1+k_2)+k_3}$?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't really been able to find a closed formula for the question you pose in keeping $k_1,k_2...k_n$ general, but nonetheless have found results which may or may not prove useful to your endeavour

For any integer $n>0$

$F_{2n+2} = (F_{n} + F_{n+2}).F_{n+1}$

$F_{2n+1} = (F_{n})^2 + (F_{n+1})^2 $

For any integer $ n> 2$

$F_{n+2} =F_{n} +F_{n-1}.F_{3}+F_{n-2}.F_{2}$

Answer (score 0):

While not a closed formula for n in general, I have found results for when n=3,4 which may or may not prove useful to your endeavour.

Using the equation above,

${ F }_{ m+n+1 }={F}_{m+1}{F}_{n+1}+{F}_{m}{F}_{n}$ and
${ F }_{ m+n-1 }={F}_{m}{F}_{n}+{F}_{m-1}{F}_{n-1}$.

The difference between the two equations implies ${ F }_{ m+n }={F}_{m+1}{F}_{n+1}-{F}_{m-1}{F}_{n-1}$.

Therefore,

${ F }_{ a+b+c}={F}_{a+1}{F}_{b+c+1}-{F}_{a-1}{F}_{b+c-1}={F}_{a+1}{F}_{b+1}{F}_{c+1}+{F}_{a+1}{F}_{b}{F}_{c}-{F}_{a-1}{F}_{b}{F}_{c}-{F}_{a-1}{F}_{b-1}{F}_{c-1}={F}_{a+1}{F}_{b+1}{F}_{c+1}+{F}_{a}{F}_{b}{F}_{c}-{F}_{a-1}{F}_{b-1}{F}_{c-1}$

And in a similar way

${F}_{a+b+c+d}={F}_{a+1}{F}_{b+1}{F}_{c+1}{F}_{d+1}+{F}_{a+1}{F}_{b+1}{F}_{c}{F}_{d}+{F}_{a}{F}_{b}{F}_{c+1}{F}_{d+1}-{F}_{a}{F}_{b}{F}_{c-1}{F}_{d-1}-{F}_{a-1}{F}_{b-1}{F}_{c}{F}_{d}-{F}_{a-1}{F}_{b-1}{F}_{c-1}{F}_{d-1}$